# Nginx rewriteurl from example.com/script.php?param=value to example.com/value

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a PHP script that accepts a single parameter.

My project structure is like the following:

```
index.php
i.php
terms.php
functions
includes
icons
resources
```

The script that I want to rewrite its URL is `i.php` from

```
example.com/i.php?icon=id
```

to

```
example.com/id
```

While making sure everything else is normally accessible (e.g. `example.com/terms.php`).

How do I do that?

**Edit**
This might be helpful. Here's my previous .htaccess that I used to use on my apache server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./i.php?icon=$1
```

Comment: what is the problem with, rewrite ^/i.php?icon=(.*) /id break;

Comment: That is neat, but not general. Eg, what if the user writes a new script called `f.php` that did a similar thing? Also, what if the query string doesn't have `icon` in it? Also, in your suggestion, you forgot to use the back reference `rewrite ^/i.php?icon=(.*) /$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working by using this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /i.php?icon=$uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like,

```
if ($query_string ~ .*=(.*)){ 
    return 301 $scheme://site.com/$1;
}
```

but it's not that simple. This will redirect **any** URL with a query string and an equal sign (not just `i.php`) to `site.com/everything_after_the_equal_sign`. If you only want this to apply to `i.php`, you'll need to create a location block for it eg.

```
location /i.php/ {
    if ($query_string ~ .*=(.*)){ 
    return 301 $scheme://site.com/$1;
}
```

If you have an existing location block like this, then this if statement needs to be added. If you're serving all PHP content from a generic location block such as

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    #your config here
}
```

then you'll need to specifically add the `/i.php/` **above** the generic block.

**Most importantly**:

**if** is evil (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)). This will apply to you if you have the if statement in the location block. If you can, try to rewrite your code to do these redirects internally. Otherwise, as stated in the docs, `if` is sometimes unavoidable.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think 301 redirect is the solution here.  I'm trying to REWRITE the url to be more readable.

Comment: Here's my website: http://testmyicon.com/
I want this url: http://testmyicon.com/i.php?icon=hb798
to become http://testmyicon.com/hb798
That's my goal